# Selecting the max with a condition in excel

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a range in excel with dates and values

http://lh4.ggpht.com/_i-hI_3gfy08/SoSIopeZUZI/AAAAAAAABEk/KjFnq57VTUc/table.png
EDIT:image added

I want to select the MAX value from the HIGH column for each YEAR (2009 would return 404, 2008 would return 390)

I've done something similar but it's using SUMIF, not MAX.

Any excel people in here that can help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three options available.

My preferred option is to create a pivot table without a helper column.

- **Option 1:** Use a pivot table

Create a pivot table of your data.

Set the row to the date field and group it by year. 
Alternately a 'Year' helper column could be used by adding a column with this formula.

```
=YEAR(A2)
```

Set the data items value portion of the pivot table to be the **MAX** of your 'High' field

- **Option 2:** Use the **DMAX** function

Add a helper column titled year with the formula

```
=YEAR(A2)
```

Then add a formula for each year

```
=DMAX(A1:C21,"High",F13:F14)
```

- **Option 3:** Use an array formula

Enter an array formula for each year using the **Ctrl-Shift-Enter** keys.

```
{=MAX(IF(YEAR(A2:A21)=2008,B2:B21))}
```

Comment: The image on this answer has expired

Answer (score 7):

The equivalent of `SUMIF` in Excel is something like this:

`{=MAX(IF(CategoryColumn="High",ValueColumn,"")}`

Where

- `CategoryColumn` is the column containing your categories (e.g., "Low", "Med", "High")
- `ValueColumn` is the column containing the data you want to get the max of

**NOTE:** This is an *array formula* so you must press **Ctrl-Shift-Enter** when entering this formula instead of just Enter. Also, don't actually type in the braces `{}`. The braces show up automatically to indicate that you've entered an array formula.

**NOTE 2:** You can actually name a range of data. For example, select the range `A1:A20`. Right-Click and select "Name a Range..." So, for this example, you can select your category column and name it `CategoryColumn`. Same with `ValueColumn`.

Array formulas allow you to do `IF` statements and other functions on a whole range of data instead of just a single value.

This example checks if the value in the "category column" is "High". If it is, it puts the neighboring "value" into the `MAX` function, otherwise it puts a blank. This gives you the maximum of all the "High" values.

P.S. I don't think the `img` tag works on this site...can't see your image.