# Excel : Select max and min Datetime in a row

Tags: excel, date, time, max, min

I've about 700 data in one row in `Excel`.

Date time `08/07/2014  10:30:00` with format :

```
DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

How do I select the `MAX` of the value in the row and the `min` ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

If A1 is your starting cell and A701 is your last cell:

paste `=MAX(A1:A701)` for maximum

paste `=MIN(A1:A701)` for minimum

Format the cell with your result in the correct Format, e.g. Date/Time

More information is for example in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274788/selecting-the-max-with-a-condition-in-excel).

Comment: Add formula in fx box.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is way late but wanted to post in case anyone has the same issue as me. I was having an issue comparing times using min/max. Excel kept returning midnight (12 AM) and formatting was not helping. I finally realized that taking the min/max of the timevalue gets me the right answer. Looks like this:

=Min(timevalue(A1),timevalue(A2))

Answer (score 1):

Max(CDATE(A)) AS 'MAX_Date
hope this is helpful... I might be posting late though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max()` and `min()` functions.

Comment: Nop, got a solution like this : 41824,4375

Answer (score 0):

Fairly easy:

use `Max` and `Min` functions:

```
=MAX(startingCell:endingCell)
=MIN(startingCell:endingCell)
```

For example, to get the maximum and minimum value of cells D1 to D100:

```
=MAX(D1:D100)
=MIN(D1:D100)
```

If you want only a selection (rather than a range) of cells:

```
=MAX(D110;E12;E19;F13)
=MIN(D110;E12;E19;F13)
```

Comment: It's in custom : DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM

Answer (score 0):

Just Use the "MAX()" and "MIN()" functions. If your row is the number 2:

=MAX(2:2) and =MIN(2:2)

Comment: @Matthijs -    Ever heard of a row reference? 2:2 is the whole row 2, just like A:A is the whole column A. That's basic Excel syntax, no?

Comment: @teylyn: I have not heard of it, my mistake. I did try the =MAX(2:2) and it returned 0 while it contained calculable data. Guess something went wrong there because it works on other rows. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: That downvote is not warranted. The answer is correct. @user3586346 you need to learn how to format numbers. Dates are numbers formatted to be displayed as dates.

Comment: I have tried to remove that downvote but wasn't able to.

Answer (score 0):

The Max() and the Min() functions as suggested by others will return the maximum and the minimum value.

These values will be displayed in the General format. You need to format them as date and time to see them as date and time.

Use `=MAX(2:2)` and `=MIN(2:2)` as suggested by Pablo Arce and then format the result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MIN() and MAX() functions with a proper range and you are getting a wrong solution, maybe the problem is the format of the "result" cell.

It is possible that the "MAX" and "MIN" functions are working properly, but the result is being displayed in wrong way. Try to apply your custom format to the cells where the MIN and MAX functions are.