# How to use MAX function with a condition?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I would like to generate data as shown in the below table. I would like to use a MAX function on column `MaxDate` so that it pulls the most recent date from the `Date` column. I would like to have the most recent date in one cell per client just like as shown. I would appreciate any suggestion.

[image]

Comment: Here is the answer for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274788/selecting-the-max-with-a-condition-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

If `Date` is in A1, please try in D2 and copied down:

```
=IF(C1<>C2,MAX(IF(C2:C11=C2,A2:A11)),"")
```