# Removing specific rows in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a data set in Excel as shown in the snippet below:

```
 Patient Number Age  State
      1         20     1
      1         20     3
      1         20     2
      2         35     1
      2         35     4
      3         62     2
      3         62     1
      3         62     3
      3         62     4
      3         62     5
```

I need to keep the last row of each patient, i.e. I need the dataset to look as follows:

```
 Patient Number Age  State
      1         20     2
      2         35     4
      3         62     5
```

Is there a simple way to do this with Excel? Since the dataset is huge and cannot do it manually

Comment: Only the state changes for each Patient number?

Comment: No I have other columns that change, I just showed a snippet to avoid large data.

Comment: Oh ok. Not sure with excel but you could save it as a CSV and write a script to do that for you. Also, see if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274788/selecting-the-max-with-a-condition-in-excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is in `A:C` columns, you can add another column with the following formula in D2:

```
=A2<>A3
```

Fill it down. Apply autofilter, choose `False` in `D` column and delete all filtered rows.

**Edit:**

This solution assumes your data is sorted by `A` column.

Comment: What does this do please? And =A2<>A3? why A3?

Comment: This formula checks if cell value is different from the next cell's value. It will return `True` only for the last value in each series.

Comment: This formula assumes `Patient Number` column is sorted.

Comment: Thanks! I did that but I cannot understand the filtering part. I selected Filter and then False and all the column turned to a value of false

Comment: That's how the filter works - it selects all the rows that are not the last. You can delete all the rows, and remove the filter. And as @zx8754 mentioned - your data needs to be sorted, as in your sample.

Comment: I see managed thanks! :) One last thing I got a lot of blank columns, is there a way to remove them automatically to get the data under each other? As manually I have a lot of work since the data is really large

Comment: I think you you want to remove blank rows, you can find one of the methods here: http://superuser.com/questions/474530

Comment: @user90790 avoid asking new questions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Enter below to `D2` and press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to make it an array formula:

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$11=A2,ROW($A$2:$A$11)))=ROW()
```

[image]

Advantage of this formula is `PatientNumber` column doesn't have to be sorted. Formula will find the last entry for each `PatientNumber`. See below, added one more row for Patient number 1:

[image]

Comment: thanks :) I have one column that contains a value depending on the previous column and when I am doing this and deleting the empty rows this column is getting a value of #REF!. Can I keep this column by saving it as a fixed value once it is calculated before I do this process?

Comment: Yes, once you have calculated your `TRUE/FALSE` use paste special as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily keep the *top* entry with Data ► Data Tools ► Remove Duplicates. To keep the *last* entry, you first need to reverse the order.

1. In an unused *Helper* column to the right put a *1* in the top row then select all of cells in that column to the bottom of your data and use Home ► Editing ► Fill ► Series to gain a column of sequential numbers.
2. Sort your data using that new column in descending order.
3. Choose Data ► Data Tools ► Remove Duplicates using only the *Patient* column as the criteria for duplication.
4. Delete the *Helper* column as it is not longer needed.

Duplicates are deleted from the bottom up so the first value for each patient will be retained.